# Draw the set $M_{4}$={(x, y) ; |xy|< 1/4}

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I want to draw the set $M_{4}$={(x, y) ; |xy|< 1/4}

My attempt is that I evaluate the expression of |xy|<1/4 depending on the values of x an y, i.e depending on the quadrant.

For the second quadrant I get the following:

x < 0 $\implies$ |x| = -x

y $\ge$0  $\implies$ |y| = y

$\implies$ |xy| =-xy < $\frac{1}{4}$ $\implies$ y > - $\frac{1}{4x}$

Which does not make any sense as the set is enclosed by the lines y=-$\frac{1}{4}$ y = $\frac{1}{4x}$, and thus for the second quadrant I should get y < - $\frac{1}{4x}$. I don't understand where I go wrong, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to consider the set in four different quadrants.

For $xy<0$, you have $-xy<\frac14$.

For $x>0$ and $y<0$,
$$
y>\frac{-1}{4x}
$$

For $x<0$ and $y>0$,
$$
y<\frac{-1}{4x}
$$

---

Notes.

The mistake you make is that for $x<0$ and $y>0$, you should have
$$
-xy<\frac14\Rightarrow y\color{red}{<}\frac{-1}{4x}
$$ because you are dividing the quantity $-x$ on both sides and it is a positive quantity. So the direction of the inequality does not change.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't understand why the red area in the second quadrant is in the set. Doesn't y > - $\frac{1}{4x}$ for the second quadrant imply that the set should be everything in the second quadrant but the area under the curve?

Comment: Where is the "second quadrant"  you refer to? $x<0$ and $y>0$?

Comment: yes exactly, x <0 and y >0

Comment: @Pi314 sorry that was my typo. Fixed. It should be $y<\frac{-1}{4x}$.

Comment: @Pi314: this is because you are dividing $-x$ on both sides of $xy<\frac{1}{4}$ and the quantity $-x$ is positive in the second quadrant. So the direction of the inequality does not change.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

An idea: draw first the two hyperbolas $\;y=\pm\cfrac1{4x}\;$ , and then "bound" the points with both coordinates different from zero belonging to $\;M_4\;$ by them. Of course, the above involves assuming $\;x\neq0\;$, but together with $\;y=0\;$ (both axis are contained in $\;M_4\;$) you shall get what you need.